# macOS new logging api (unified logging) log stream

Tags: terminal, bash, logs, command-line

Questions:

**1)** How can we redirect the `log` *stream* from stdin to, for example `lnav`? Currently, I use bash | (pipe), but I would like to hear if there is a better way to do it - the pipe buffer flow is too fast for `lnav` to process and format it properly –  any ideas/solutons here?

I don't know how to set a *bridge* (I don't want to write/read to the filesystem) between log and any other shell process without pipe in bash directly.

**2)** How can I properly use the stream from `log stream` to put the JSON direct into `mongodb`?

`log stream --style=json` output  makes it a lot easier to hack some awesome node analytical/statistical or visual parsers.

`log stream --style=syslog --level=info` can make one dizzy, with 
**--predicate** you can narrow it down to more readable flow:

`log stream --style syslog  --predicate \
'senderImagePath contains[cd] "TimeMachine"' --info`

The API is a good step forward – but I'd like to have more transition time with `syslog` until I forget about it and the uhmmmm the new memory *persistent* log since `10.12.1 public beta` is not entirely to my liking since I simply don't get any new log files in `/private/var/log` (can also be my config error/mistake though)

*update 1* – https://developer.apple.com/reference/os/1891852-logging#1682426

Comment: For others who haven't used `lnav`: http://lnav.org

Comment: lnav needs some file/stream as input. Trying to pipe/redirect "log stream" to lnav is a very bad idea, since lnav cant keep up with the amount log stream spits out. Don't take my word though and try it yourself ;-) I redirect log stream into mongodb by and then skim through the database later, lnav included. the `log stream` can spit .json formatted data so you can easily pipe it into something more usable, or hack a syslog redirection, just be careful since it can literally overflow you with data when using `--level=debug`